# Update a date modified from a query in access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a form with a macro that updates its table field "Date Modified" when ever a user makes a change. The problem is that we also have a update query that users can modify the data but when using this method the "Date Modified" field does not get updated.

Is there a way I can get it to auto fill in this field when the query makes an update to that field?

Cheers,
Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the field directly in your UDPATE query.

```
UPDATE myTable
SET foo = bar, [Date Modified] = Now()
WHERE ...
```